# What test would be appropriate for a table containing data on number of visits for several individuals?

Tags: count-data

I have a table containing rows with count data for several individual animals. The counts represent the number of daytime visits that the individual animals made to a site over many days.  I have divided each day into 10 discrete one-hour periods (the columns).  Thus, each table cell is the number of visits made by that particular individual during a particular one-hour period.  What would be an appropriate statistical test for this type of data table?  My null hypothesis is that there is no difference in the number of visits across the 10 periods for any particular individual.

Comment: How many animals are there?

Comment: I have data for 15 individual animals (15 rows) and each column gives the total number of visits by each animal over the 2-month period of daily observations.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you may need two-ways ANOVA.

Try these links:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-way_analysis_of_variance
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lZFmFuZGQTk